# Compare data to display results within 1000 of each other

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I currently have a sample table as below:

> ```
>   Country    |  Sessions
>    US             1000  
>    UK              500  
>    US             2000  
>    BR             7000
>    CA             3000
> ```

The MySQL query I am looking help with is to get the output as follows, that displays the country name pairs that are within '1000' of each other

Sample Output:

> ```
>   Country_A    |  Country_B
>    US               UK   
>    UK               US  
>    US               CA  
>    CA               US
> ```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What's your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: What do you have "US" twice? And which do you want to compare?

Comment: Anyway, ABS and JOIN could both be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT a.Country AS Country_A
     , b.Country AS Country_B
  FROM my_table a
  JOIN my_table b ON ABS(a.Sessions - b.Sessions) <= 1000
   AND a.Country <> b.Country;
```